# PDO SQLite3 connection failure when database is in different folder

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I'm trying to connect to a sqlite3 database from php, but I'm hitting a brick wall when I want to place my db somewhere convenient and outside of web accesible space. When db file is in the same folder as my php script it runs ok, but when I place it somewhere else - silent fail.

I've written up a simple checker so it would be easier to understand what I mean

```
<?php
$files = array(
   'data.db',
    getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'data.db',
   'some_inner_folder' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'data.db',
    getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'some_inner_folder' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'data.db'
);

foreach($files as $file) {
    if(file_exists($file))
        echo $file, ' found<br/>';
    else
        echo $file, ' not found!<br/>';
    try {
        $db = new PDO('sqlite:host=' . $file);
        if($db)
            echo 'connection to ', $file, ' made succesfully<br/>';
    } catch (PDOException $error) {
        echo 'error connecting to ', $file, ' error message: ', $error->getMessage(), '<br/>';
    }
    $db = null;
}
```

Output turned out to be:

```
data.db found
connection to data.db made succesfully
C:\Web\data.db found
error connecting to C:\Web\data.db error message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file
some_inner_folder\data.db found
error connecting to some_inner_folder\data.db error message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file
C:\Web\some_inner_folder\data.db found
error connecting to C:\Web\some_inner_folder\data.db error message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file
```

C:\Web\data.db and C:\Web\some_inner_folder\data.db has the same contents (file copy&paste)

PHP Version 5.3.6, Windows 7 x64

PDO drivers mysql, sqlite, sqlite2

SQLite Library  3.7.4

I'm not really seeing why it doesn't work.

Problem solved

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:host=' . $file);
```

should read like this:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:' . $file);
```

Turns out pdo_sqlite doesn't need 'host='

Comment: What happens when you use forward slashes instead of the Win32-specific backslashes provided by `DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR`?

Comment: put the php file that creates the connection to db in the same folder as the db then just require the php file with `require_once('abspath/connect.php')` where abspath is the absolute path to connect.php?

Comment: Are you able to `fopen` the file?

Comment: also, the directory that contains the db file should be writable

Comment: if(fopen($file, 'r+')) returns successful. some_inner_folder and both data.db files have full control for all users, but that should matter a lot, since it's a windows box.

Comment: As of 'abspath/connect.php', it would run without errors, but that is a workaround, and there should be a real solution, because I really don't want to end up with unnecessary additional files everywhere I have databases. Hope you understand what I mean :)

Comment: @PalmTree I totally understand.  Did you try to make the directory of the db writable?

Comment: Trevor, it's a windows box, no chmod's involved. the thing is, I've already solved it, take a look at the last four lines of original post. But anyway, thanks for effort while trying to help :)

Comment: LOL i noticed that but i was embarrassed to say something about it in case it was something necessary

Answer (score 0):

When we were coding the database layer for Drupal 7 we found that PDO have many error modes and only exception is worth a damn. `$driver_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;` this will make the silent failure a lot more noisy.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a permissions problem on the other folder.  It must be capable of creating and writing the file (ie you must be able to write to the directory and the file).